# scala sort list and get nth element

Tags: scala

`val Y = List (1,4,3,5,9,7)      //> Y  : List[Int] = List(1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 7)
    Y(2)                            //> res1: Int = 3
    Y.sorted                        //> res2: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9)
    Y.sorted(2)                     //> ERROR
    // But the following works
    val z = Y.sorted                //> z  : List[Int] = List(1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9)
    z(2)                            //> res2: Int = 4`

How do i get the element at index 2 of the sorted list without assigning it to a new variable ?

Comment: The Problem is that .sorted is compiled to .sorted(...default...) and when you call sorted(2) you pass the argument 2 to the method sorted() => sorted(2) so you would need to call .sorted(..)(2) or .sortWith(_ < _)(2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
Y.sorted.apply(2)
```

The reason you receive an error is because `sorted` takes an implicit argument of type `Ordering`, and the Scala compiler tries to interpret that `2` as the value for the implicit param (passed explicitly), which ends up with an error because the types don't match.

Comment: Indeed: `def sorted[B >: A](implicit ord: Ordering[B]): Repr`